# How do I access the new missions?

Tags: ios, jetpack-joyride

There was an update to Jetpack Joyride released today, which makes me consider replaying the game (I lost all my progress when I updated to iOS5).

However, I am a bit confused by how I actually get the new missions.

The update text includes the following:

> Please note that the new mission system is only playable AFTER
>   prestiging at least once. If you have already prestiged and get the
>   update, any mission you get after your current missions will
>   automatically transition over to the new ones, yay!

What do they mean by "prestiging at least once"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prestiging in *Jetpack Joyride* means you have completed various given missions and earned enough stars to level up past level 15. The levels 1-15 require earning progressively more stars to move to the next level. The missions to earn stars are things like:

- Fly 300M in the Profit Bird in a Single Run
- Rub your head against the roof for 1000 meters
- etc.

If you level up past level 15, you will be given the option to Prestige. Once you do so, you get a shiny badge on your profile, and then you should be able to access the new missions in the update.

After you Prestige, Level 16 is like starting back out at Level 1, when you hit level 30, you can Prestige again, rinse and repeat. I do not know if there is a cap, but I'm at level 57 currently.